# PAGE NOT FOUND with url in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am just learning Django and have hit my first question.  In the HTML page itself, I can view the page and see the header I created.  However, when I type in the url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) it will not show.  Instead, it says PAGE NOT FOUND.  Here is my code.

This is the relevant portion of code from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This is the code from urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$/', home_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is the code from views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html", {})
```

This is the code from home_page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

The first three files are in a directory within the src folder and the last file is in another directory but still within the src folder.  I did notice that I did not have a **pycache** folder when I started the project for some reason (even though the instructor from the video did have one when he started) but I am not sure if that has anything to do with anything.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your url regres is wrong

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: WHOOPS!  Thank a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('', home_page),
    #or url(r'home/', home_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

if you are choosing the second method, you should go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/home for viewing the page